# Is there any way to draw the corrupted images in the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw an image in the canvas. The image that I'm using is got as base64 string from the server. For testing purpose, I have saved the image to the disk both at the client and the server while debugging. The image is saved fine. While drawing in the canvas, the image is not rendered in Chrome and Firefox. But it works fine in IE 11.Is there any way to make the images draw in all the browsers.

```
var base64String = "data:image/png;base64,SUkqANZ1AQAAEbQhURQh0dUQ6mh0dHQ62ao6GIEQkpodHSEOqKiHXodDqaoh1NOqKaOjo6HU0dUQ6mqIdeh16dSUJQqJCmh0hUR0OvQ6HU0OqIdenXodTQ69DqidTVEdOpodIXIdDr1RDokXIdeh0OuQ6HXodDr0Oh16HQ6oh16HQ6mh1NDqioi6XS0OqKidcnXp16HTr0OqIdHQ69Dodch1PHX469D1EOvQ6HU0OqIdch0hUQ2h0dF0DVEOqI6HS2tgiHQ65Do6Qh1NDqiQqIdHU0OhiOhCHU0dOqL0OpqiHXodDpe0XR0OvQ6QqIdHVE69DqaHXpOADuamqIujo6IR1t1RHVEhHR0dBqiOi6OkI6BobS8IQgRF1RHSEDR0dA0hNypCEOqIhAilqtlCS1uEDSEDQmhpURCmh0XR1sYqI6Bo6og0NI6QkJCLoGhpSLpCGJCEJCQjoQh0dIVEdBEDRmACU.." //only few of the string is shared
function drwImage(base64String) {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1);
}
img.src = base64String;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: add an example of your base64 input string please

Comment: *"the corrupted images"* - Huh?

Comment: Hi @Infer-on, I have shared few of the string in the above edited code snippet. Since the string is too large to share, I have shared few. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems something related to the serialized image, as you can see in the snippet below, it works on Chrome, I used an [online encoder](https://www.base64-image.de/).
As you can read [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) the datauri is almost supported at all.

```js
  var base64String = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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" //only few of the string is shared

   drwImage(base64String);


function drwImage(b) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      console.log('load')
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1);
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    img.onerror = function() {
      console.log('error')
    }
    img.src = b;
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Infer-on, are you saying there may be an error in the encoding? I have not tried the online encoder. Let me try it.

Comment: the datauri is supported at all browsers. There is no issue in it. I have used other images to render in the canvas. If a corrupted string is faced, how to rectify it and render the proper image?

Comment: I am sorry, but I doubt you can restore a corrupted serialized datauri